# Run ActiveMQ offline?

Tags: activemq-classic, offline

Is there a way to run ActiveMq offline?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by offline.

You can start a broker inside of a Java application simply by creating a `ConnectionFactory` like so:

`ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");`

This broker would only be accessible from within the Java application where it was created using the `vm://localhost` transport.

Bruce

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do something like "running offline" by [embedding broker into JVM](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html). This is usually done for (unit) testing.

```
BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
// configure the broker
broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
broker.start();
```